# What are virtual functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, virtual-functions

According to one definition of virtual functions:

> In object-oriented programming, in languages such as C++, a virtual
>   function or virtual method is an inheritable and overridable function
>   or method for which dynamic dispatch is facilitated.

How would this look for functions in javascript?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719481/virtual-function-in-javascript

Comment: @bee: Not really. That question asks *how* to do a virtual function, and the only answer to it says "don't", that the semantics are different (without going into details), and then makes small changes to the implementation in the question. That answer doesn't address this question's question, which is the dupe criterion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How would this look for functions in javascript?

The concept largely doesn't apply to JavaScript.

The concept of virtual and non-virtual functions (methods, really) requires the concept of a *type* of reference to an object, as distinct from what the object *is*. For instance, you might have a `BaseFoo` type with a `bar` method, and a `DerivedFoo` type that derives from it and overrides `bar`. Later, if you have a `BaseFoo`-typed variable `b` referring to a `DerivedFoo` object, when you call `b.bar()`, you'll get `DerivedFoo`'s `bar` if `bar` is virtual, but `BaseFoo`'s `bar` if `bar` is non-virtual. But if you have a `DerivedFoo`-typed variable `d` referring to a `DerivedFoo` object, `d.bar()` always calls `bar` whether it's virtual or not. The *type* of the variable you're using to refer to the object determines what method gets called if the method is non-virtual.

None of that exists in JavaScript. References to objects are *untyped*. When you call `o.bar()`, you get the property `bar` from that object and call the function it refers to.

If you wanted to stretch a point, given JavaScript's prototypical inheritance mechanism, you could say that in some sense, all JavaScript "methods" are virtual, if we **very** loosely say a "method" is a function attached to an object property (although in ES2015+, "method" has a more specific meaning in JavaScript than that, but still fits that definition). That's because when you look up a property on an object, if it has its own property with that name, that's the one you get; you only get the one from its prototype if it doesn't have its own. But that's probably stretching a point, perhaps too far.

Comment: Ah, so all JavaScript functions are virtual function in the sense that they can be inherited and overridden, but not in the sense that they are defined as belonging to a castable type; there are no types, and so there can be no dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @bitstrider: Pretty much, yup. Objects arguably have a type of sorts, but references do not (and thus no dynamic dispatch in the comp sci sense).